# Подскажите про использование параметров PARAM в EVAL ACTION

Tags: lsfusion

Вместо этого

```
SHOW  formBf001ComReport  OBJECTS calcP = c, task = cc DOCKED NOWAIT MANAGESESSION;
```

Выполнять это, чтобы подставлять имя формы текстом:

```
EVAL ACTION  'SHOW ' + 'formBf001ComReport' 
    + ' OBJECTS calcP = param1, task = param2 DOCKED NOWAIT MANAGESESSION ' PARAMS c ,cc ;
```

но так param1 не найден.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обращение к параметрам в EVAL ACTION (как и в других местах, где нужно обращаться к безымянным параметрам) осуществляется при помощи синтаксиса $<номер параметра> (например $1)

```
EVAL ACTION  'SHOW ' + 'formBf001ComReport' 
+ ' OBJECTS calcP = $1, task = $2 DOCKED NOWAIT MANAGESESSION ' PARAMS c ,cc ;
```

Но действительно, в документации это почему-то не описано.